# Cron expression not giving proper date?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I want to run a cron job on every day of first week of December.

But my cron job instead runs on second week of December.

Below is the code

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;

import org.quartz.CronExpression;

public class CronExpressionTest{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String expression = "0 0 0 ? 12 2#1,3#1,4#1,5#1,6#1,7#1,1#1 *";
        CronExpression cronExpression = new CronExpression(expression);
        Date date = cronExpression.getNextValidTimeAfter(new Date());
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

If you see the calendar below, job should run on 1st December for the first time, but it runs on 7th December.

[image]

**Edit 1 :**

It looks like week in cron starts from first Sunday instead of 1st day of the month.

**Edit 2:-**

Apparently cron expression "0 0 0 ? 12 2#1,3#1,4#1,5#1,6#1,7#1 *" starts on 1st Dec which is correct but "0 0 0 ? 12 2#1,3#1,4#1,5#1,6#1,7#1,1#1 *" starts on 7th Dec as I added 1#1 (1st sunday of the month).

Answer (score 0):

According to the Quartz Javadoc, only one '#' expression is allowed for day-of-week field:

> If the '#' character is used, there can only be one expression in the day-of-week field ("3#1,6#3" is not valid, since there are two expressions).

Reference: http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/CronExpression.html